# Replace and eval in Jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a string like this as Jinja variable:

```
foo-VERSION-bar
```

I want to replace `VERSION` with `{{ grains.lsb_distrib_release }}` and I want this to get evaluated.

if `grains.lsb_distrib_release` contains `123` I want the result to be `foo-123-bar`.

How to replace **and** eval in jinja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set value of your grain to a variable:

```
{% set version = salt['grains.get']('lsb_distrib_release', {}) %}
```

Use Jinja replace function:

```
{{ "foo-VERSION-bar"|replace("VERSION", version) }}
```

Comment: I changed my answer to replace something in a string, but to be honest it is quite hard to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Without using replace Jinja filter, you can use its concatenation possibilities

```
{{ 'foo-' ~ salt['grains.get']('lsb_distrib_release') ~ '-bar' }}
```